# Laços com array de arrays não funciona

Tags: javascript, array

Por que o `y` no segundo `for` não "corre"?

```
var i = 0;
    var bd = new Array();
    bd[i++] = new Array(10,11,'Daniel');
    bd[i++] = new Array(12,12,'Augusto');
    bd[i++] = new Array(13, 12, 'Olavo');
```

Vejam que corro as coordenadas deste array bidimensional em `x` e `y` - um laço duplo:

```
for (x=1 ; x<=i ; x++){
   for(y=0 ; y<=2; y++){
       alert(y);
       if (y=10){ document.write(bd[x][y]); 
       // O Retorno é 10,11,'Daniel'
       }
   }
}
```

Coloquei um "alert" para verem que o valor não sai de zero. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Mas, qual é a dúvida mesmo? Não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor sua dúvida?

Comment: Obrigado por perguntarem! Reeditei o enunciado. O meu codigo nao esta funcionando. Dá erro de sintaxe. Devo estar cometendo algum erro crasso.

Answer (score 2):

A sua lógica está correta, segue um exemplo com o comando `push` que serve justamente para incluir um registro no final de um `array`:

```js
/* Inicializa a variável */
// A estrutura final ficará db[linha][coluna]
var db = [];

/* Insere registros */
db.push([1, 2, 'Teste 1']);
db.push([2, 3, 'Teste 2']);
db.push([3, 3, 'Teste 3']);

/* Exibe um registro no console */
console.log(db[1]);

/* Exibe uma célula no console */
console.log(db[2][2]);

/* Varre todos registros e monta uma tabela */

// Loop pelas linhas
for (var iRow = 0; iRow < db.length; iRow++) {
  
  // Aqui criamos a tag <tr>
  var $tr = document.createElement('tr');
  
  // Loope pelas colunas
  for (var iCol = 0; iCol < db[iRow].length; iCol++) {
    
    // Aqui criamos a tag <td>
    var $td = document.createElement('td');
    
    // Aqui pegamos o conteúdo da célula pela linha/coluna e colocamos dentro da tag <td>
    $td.innerHTML = db[iRow][iCol];
    
    // Aqui incluímos a tag <td> dentro da tag <tr>
    $tr.appendChild($td);
  }
  
  // Aqui incluímos a tag <tr> dentro da tag <tbody> da tabela (pelo ID)
  document.getElementById('tabela').appendChild($tr);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Código</td>
      <td>Nome</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabela"></tbody>
</table>
```

### Quanto ao problema do seu código

É uma erro de sintaxe na linha `for(y=0; y<=i; Y++){` pois o "terceiro y" está em maiúsculo. E como no javascript o nome das variáveis são *case sensitive*, ou seja, o nome precisa ser idêntico incluindo maiúsculas ou minúsculas.

Segue abaixo o código corrigido:

```js
var i = 0;
    var bd = new Array();
    bd[i++] = new Array(10,11,'Daniel');
    bd[i++] = new Array(12,12,'Augusto');
    bd[i++] = new Array(13, 12, 'Olavo');

for (x=1 ; x<=i ; x++){
   for(y=0; y<=i; y++){
       if (y == 10){ document.write(bd[x][y]); 
       // O Retorno é 10,11,'Daniel'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Interessante este código! Acho que posso utilizar para outro propósito de criar arrays zerados e ir transferindo strings de um array para o outro. Algo mais dinamico.

A minha meta nesse codigo é fazer algo que um usuário nao-programador precise dar manutencao, entao tem que ser mega facil de visualizar e editar. Ainda vou precisar evoluir o codigo para pegar os aniversarios na faixa do D-4 e D+3, mas ai sao outros quinhentos e a parte mais facil. Por ora, preciso so achar algum erro de logica nesse codigo postado.

Answer (score 1):

O seu array `bd` consiste de 3 linhas numeradas de 0 a 2. Cada linha tem um outro array com colunas numeradas de 0 a 2 também. Ao final da parte de popular o array, o valor de `i` será 3.

Agora vejamos o seu código:

```
for (x=1 ; x<=i ; x++){
   for(y=0 ; y<=2; y++){
       alert(y);
       if (y=10){ document.write(bd[x][y]); 
       // O Retorno é 10,11,'Daniel'
       }
   }
}
```

Agora, vejamos os seus problemas:

- No primeiro `for`, o `x` vai de 1 até 3. Mas as linhas são de 0 a 2!
- No `if`, você está usando `y=10`, e não `y == 10`. Isso faz com que `y` mude para 10 logo na primeira iteração quando ele era 0. No `for`, ele então passa para com o `y++;` e então ele avalia `y<=2`, caindo fora do `for`.
- Mesmo usando `y == 10`, uma vez que no segundo `for`, o `y` vai de 0 até 2, ele nunca será 10!

Acho que o que você queria era isso abaixo. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> para ver isso funcionando.

```js
var i = 0;
var bd = new Array();
bd[i++] = new Array(10, 11, 'Daniel');
bd[i++] = new Array(12, 12, 'Augusto');
bd[i++] = new Array(13, 12, 'Olavo');

document.write('i = ' + i + '<br><br>');

for (var x = 0; x < i; x++) {
   for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
       document.write(bd[x][y] + '<br>');
   }
   document.write('<br>');
}
```